# calabash-android: `Cucumber::Ast` no longer exists

Tags: android, ruby, testing, calabash

I'm starting with calabash and I can't make run the test. The test is very simple, just press one TextView:

```
Feature: Login feature
    Scenario: Given I am on the Login page 
    touch("TextView id:'com.tae.store:id/option_bag'")
```

But I always have the same error:

Feature: Login feature

```
  Scenario: Given I am on the Login page # features/my_first.feature:3
      touch("TextView id:'com.tae.store:id/option_bag'")
  `Cucumber::Ast` no longer exists. These classes have moved into the `Cucumber::Core::Ast` namespace, but may not have the same API. (RuntimeError)
  ./features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb:8:in `Before'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/my_first.feature:3 # Scenario: Given I am on the Login page

1 scenario (1 failed)
0 steps
0m6.173s
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 (I've tried also with Ruby 2.0.0).

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered this issue a couple of times while trying to set up Calabash and Cucumber. I found the issue had to do with the version of the Cucumber gem that I was using. Several different sources mentioned that the newer Calabash gems don't work with **beta** Cucumber releases (reference: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/issues/479)

To solve this, I installed an older cucumber gem and removed the newer one

```
gem install cucumber -v 1.3.17
gem uninstall cucumber -v 2.0.0.beta.3
```

After doing so, I was able to run my tests without errors popping up.
Hopefully this helps someone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you are misunderstanding the structure of Calabash tests.
Here is how it should look like:

In file `features/my_first.feature` (this is the file where you put your user story)

```
Feature: Login feature
  Scenario: Check login page
    Given I am on the Login page
```

`step_definitions/steps.rb` (this is the file where you are defining steps used in `*.feature` files)

```
Given /^I am on the Login page$/ do
  touch "TextView id:'option_bag'"
end
```

I recommend you to read calabash-android wiki here: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android and Cucumber Book: https://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book :)